# angular post method with parameters and files

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I need somehow to upload couple of images and set of parameters in one POST request. I have a PHP service for that, that get parameters from POST and from $FILES variable.

```
$name  = $_POST['name'];
$text  = $_POST['text'];
$files = $_FILES;
```

Here is my JS code:

```
   $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "/Api/PostStuff",            
        headers: { 'Content-Type': false },

        transformRequest: function (data) {

             var formData = new FormData();

             formData.append("name", angular.toJson(data.name));
             formData.append("text", angular.toJson(data.text));

             for (var i = 0; i < data.files; i++) {
                formData.append("file" + i, data.files[i]);
             }

             return formData;                
        },

        data: { name: $scope.name, text: $scope.text,  files: $scope.files }
    }).
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("success!");
    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("failed!");
    });
```

I don't see a mistake but it does not work.

Comment: First of all you probably mean $_FILES in PHP, Second, what does debugger show? can you acknowledge, that the request is being made?

Comment: Yes, I got response from server and the server doesn't see parameters in POST

Comment: try to change $_POST into file_get_contents("php://input"); since you are sending a json that has to be parsed

Comment: I think I don't understand. What you mean?

Comment: how to send not a JSON but?

Comment: In your PHP script: put this : $form = file_get_contents("php://input");

then print_r($form) and work your way out.

Comment: How to make correct POST request not in JSON format, to avoid file_get_contents.. method and acces over $_POST and $_FILES?

Comment: first you need to set enctype to multipart/form-data , second you need to serialise your data, lets say in transformResponse

Comment: I tried that you suggest yesterday and the response from print_r was empty string. Also array $_FILES and _$POST are empty.